# "Simple auto-indentation" mode in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, spyder, auto-indent

In Python IDE Spyder I frequently run into issues with the automatic indentation upon pressing `<enter>`, despite already having disabled as many indentation features as possible (Tools → Preferences → Editor → Advanced Settings). This includes undesirably deep indentation when using nested parenthesis, and in a few cases outright bugs. An example would be

```
if True: # <enter>, <tab>
    x = f(
            a = lengthy_expression, # automatic indentation undesirably deep
            b = lengthy_expression)
```

or as of Spyder 3.1.1

```
assert f(x) == 1
          wrongly_indented_statement()
```

I would rather prefer for the automatic indentation to simply preserve the indentation-level of the previous line, leaving extra-indentation for multi-line expressions to the user, e.g.

```
if True: # <enter>, <tab>
    x = f( # <enter>, <tab>
        a = lengthy_expression, # <enter> 
        b = lengthy_expression) # <enter>
```

Is there some such "simple auto-indentation" mode in spyder?

Answer (score 5):

(*Spyder developer here*) No, there isn't. We'll try to fix these bugs in one of our next releases (3.1.3 or 3.1.4)

Comment: has there been any movement on this? still seems an issue as of 4.0b4

Comment: The cases reported here will be working as expected in 4.0b5.